# Mac OS X - Why doesn't the 'open' command pass parms for me from a bash script?

Tags: mac, bash, terminal, console

I am attempting to run this 'open' command through a bash script, but the arguments aren't passing for some reason.  Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check to see if the arguments are valid? I was able to pass multiple websites to open in Chrome like this:

```
open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' --args http://stackoverflow.com http://superuser.com
```

They then opened right up in Chrome as expected

**EDIT:** After some trial and error, I've also realized that Chrome must be *Quit* before the command is run in order for the CLI arguments to take effect.

Comment: I'll try that with the quotes and see if it makes a difference.  The arguments are definitely valid.  If I run the statement at a bash prompt, it's fine.  When I put it into a bash script, then it doesn't work. Are you sure you tried a script and not just the prompt?

Comment: Yep, I just threw the above line into a bash script and it opened those pages without issue!

Comment: strange...I do notice though that your arguments don't need --'s in front of them. I wonder if that has something to do with it?

Comment: That might be it but I've seen other superuser.com posts with open commands using -- arguments... Perhaps the Chrome app has a command line reference somewhere?